# Using substring to strip text from text file & insert into SQL Server database & create script text file as result

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, bulkinsert

**Database Specification:** SQL Server 2012
**Problem Statement:** 
I need a sql query (store procedure or function or set-base query … you the expert) to assist with processing 4.1 million records in efficient time. These records reside in a text file and therefore need to inserted into a database table. Note each record consist of the following fields at different offset values: 
Herewith the offset values for only the first 6 columns...
      ,LTRIM(SUBSTRING([TABLE],1,13)) --National_id
      ,LTRIM(SUBSTRING([TABLE],14,43)) --Errmsg
      ,LTRIM(SUBSTRING([TABLE],57,8))  --DeceasedDTE
      ,LTRIM(SUBSTRING([TABLE],65,50)) --DeceasedReason 
      ,LTRIM(SUBSTRING([TABLE],115,45)) --Surname
      ,LTRIM(SUBSTRING([TABLE],158,50)) --FirstNames
Note the FirstNames column could contain 3 string values separated by a space … FName1, FName2, Fname3…
This is where I’m struggling to strip this column with more than 2 string values … only because this column doesn’t work with offset values …

I have the following 3 records as a sample ... these records need to be stored in a text file and used as input..

```
    Copy this to a text file named: Deceased.txt
    000101001118 IDENTITY NUMBER NOT NUMERIC
0001010061181PERSON DECEASED                            19990101OBSTRUCTIVE AIRWAYS SYNDROME                      BABA                                         NOWEZILE
0001010077097                                                                                                     COERTZEN                                     AZIL CUBITT JONO
```

**Desired Result:**
1. Insert each record to a sql server table.
The table will have the following columns:
    National_id   Errmsg   DeceasedDTE   DeceasedReason  Surname FirstNames 
    First_Initial Second_Initial Third_Initial FName1 FName2 FName3

Also note the `FirstNames` is separated with a space and I need them spit up into each FName1, FName2 and FName3 ... with its corresponding first letter that makes up the initial..

1. I then need to create a script send to a .txt file that creates an insert statement for each record with the following columns... national_id, surname, First_Initial, Second_Initial,Third_Initial, First_Name, Second_Name, Third_Name
   E.G.
   Set @Insert = "insert into prodmgr.t_unverified (national_id, surname, First_Initial, Second_Initial,Third_Initial, First_Name, Second_Name, Third_Name) values ('"

NOTE:

DECEASED.TXT (3 RECORDS)
        000101001118 IDENTITY NUMBER NOT NUMERIC
    0001010061181PERSON DECEASED                            19990101OBSTRUCTIVE AIRWAYS SYNDROME                      BABA                                         NOWEZILE
    0001010077097                                                                                                     COERTZEN                                     AZIL CUBITT JONO

TABLE:DECEASED (3 RECORDS)

National_id Errmsg DeceasedDTE DeceasedReason Surname FirstNames First_Initial Second_Initial Third_Initial FName1 FName2 FName3

RESULT IN TEXT FILE: (2 RECORDS)

insert into prodmgr.t_unverified (national_id, surname, First_Initial, Second_Initial,Third_Initial, First_Name, Second_Name, Third_Name) values ('0001010061181',’BABA’,’N’,’’,’’,’NOWEZILE’,’’,’’)

insert into prodmgr.t_unverified (national_id, surname, First_Initial, Second_Initial,Third_Initial, First_Name, Second_Name, Third_Name) values (0001010077097,’COERTZEN’,’A’,’C’,’J’,’AZIL’,’CUBITT’,’JONO’)

Comment: Please format your question.

Comment: I greated images to make it more understandable... but I dont have all prevliages..

Comment: Upload photos on some web service and post the links in your question.

Comment: Thansk I got it... https://plus.google.com/photos?enfplm&hl=en&utm_source=lmnavbr&utm_medium=embd&utm_campaign=lrnmre&rtsl=1&gpsrc=selm0#photos/yourphotos?pid=5954248014286171250&oid=109872532996408895903

Comment: I don't think it's public. Try using a different image hosting service .. like imgur.com

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/pTy0D9Y.png?1

Comment: @Radu Gheorghiu: Does the image help with the explination... ?